# Improving ArcMap Batch Production of PDF Maps Performance?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, performance, pdf

I am producing 1,500 PDF maps and was wondering what changes I can make to either my machine or to ArcMap to help speed things along. Currently, it takes 5:45 - 6 minutes to produce four maps. If I change the output format to PNG, this goes down to 1:46 minutes, but I need to output PDFs.

My specs are:
-one geodatabase
-20 or so different feature classes
-python script to cycle through 30 different layers for all 50 states
-running on local machine
-ArcMap 10.6.1

What I've tried:
-clearing cache in ArcMap
-rebooting machine
-enabling hardware acceleration and background processing
-attribute indexes on query fields
-spatial indexes added
-ArcGIS cache manager declared high priority in Windows Task Manager

Any suggestions/tips that I can try to speed this up?

Comment: Are the geodatabase and the output PDFs both stored on the local machine? Sounds like it. If they're on a mechanical HDD, is installing an SSD an option?

Comment: Both stored on a local machine. Installing an SSD may be a possibility, but haven't escalated to that point yet. Unless other options don't work, maybe i'll try it.

Comment: You might fiddle with your settings in the pdf export dialog box tabs, such as output quality, dpi,  attribute information, etc. and add what you have tried to your question.  There is a File - Analyze menu option that might provide some useful info to you.

Comment: Have you tried lowering the pdf quality as much as you can accept, dpi, compression etc.? You can also try clipping the data and remove all layers that are not used since it will "draw" all data, even outside the display extent.

Comment: Do you really need PDFs because of their end features (measuring if geo-enabled, layers control, Illustrator conversion)? If not, high resolution graphics files can be converted to PDF, multipage too, pretty easily. Plus, you could turn off layer support, attribute support,  and geo to make exports go somewhat faster. But, I am used to much longer export times than yours.

Comment: @BERA - since each map is unique, I have controls in the script to only show what's in the zoom extent. I can't lower the quality much without sacrificing the quality of the logo I have in the map.

Comment: @danak - I want PDF's because that's what the client needs. My only concern with exporting out as a PNG or another image format, and then converting to PDF (outside of ArcGIS?), would be any conversion issues that may pop up? Is converting a high res PNG to PDF risk-free?

Comment: 1500 is a lot. Never tried myself on PDF export, but multiprocessing works well on big tasks like raster projection... Perhaps try using range export?

Comment: Are you using data driven pages for the 50 states?

Comment: I've never had issues with converting images to PDF, but I don't do this often. If they need the text to be searchable (for public documentation/ADA compliance), the conversion won't help.

Answer (score 2):

This script took 38 seconds to export 100 pages:

```
import time, os
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
import arcpy
t0 = time.time()
def ddpExport(i):
    outFolder=r'f:\AERIALS\PDFs'
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\TOOLS\_wbench.mxd")
    ddp = mxd.dataDrivenPages
    fromPage=10*i+1
    toPage=fromPage+10
    for pageID in range(fromPage,toPage):
        ddp.currentPageID = pageID
        code='PAGE_%s' %str(pageID).zfill(5)
        fName='%s%s%s.pdf' %(outFolder,os.sep,code)
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd,fName,"PAGE_LAYOUT", resolution =72)
    return '%s-%s' %(fromPage,toPage-1)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Pool(4)
    aList=list(range(10))
    print(p.map(ddpExport, aList))
    print ('%i seconds' %(time.time()-t0))
```

vs 95 seconds from mxd itself. Yes, it will take 10-15 seconds to load arcpy, but overall you should expect significant time saving, when using multiprocessing for that task. See help on how to reduce size as well, e.g. set layers_attributes = "NONE". No improvements found when exporting to SSD, but the job was too small.

UPDATE THAT WORKS EVEN FASTER:

```
import time, os
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
import arcpy
t0 = time.time()
def ddpExport(i):
    outFolder=r'c:\SCRATCH\BACKUP'
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\TOOLS\_wbench.mxd")
    ddp = mxd.dataDrivenPages
    fromPage=10*i+1
    toPage=fromPage+10
    fName='%s%sPages_%s.pdf' %(outFolder,os.sep,str(i+1).zfill(3))
    ddp.exportToPDF(fName,"RANGE", '%s-%s' %(fromPage,toPage-1),
                                  resolution =72,
                                  embed_fonts="False",
                                  layers_attributes="NONE")
    return '%s-%s' %(fromPage,toPage-1)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Pool(5)
    aList=list(range(10))
    print(p.map(ddpExport, aList))
    print ('%i seconds' %(time.time()-t0))
```